# Updating thermostats to single system

Tags: heating, thermostat

I have a three floors in my house, each controlled by it's own thermostat (separate air handlers and mechanical valves on furnace).  Baseboard heat.

The three thermostats are controlled separately, and it's getting a pain to manage them all.  I would like to update to a smart thermometer (Honeywell Lync, Nest, Ecobee), but I was wondering if there was another system out there that could control the three zones correctly without having to install three thermostats.   Any thoughts?

My only other thing I would like to solve is the multiple rooms in one zone.  Particular thermostats have a "remote" temperature sensor to help regulate heat.   Does anybody have any thoughts?

Comment: The thermostats are used to determine when each zone needs heating/cooling.  You may be able to eliminate them, but some form of sensor will still be required in each zone. Otherwise the system would never know when to turn on/off.

Comment: You have a furnace *and* baseboard heat?

Comment: @isherwood: My house has baseboard radiators headed by a central furnace. It's not uncommon in my area.

Answer (score 1):

There are other ways to control multi-zones, but they're usually more expensive than smart thermostats.  Ecobees are the only thermostats that can be (affordably) controlled in groups via their web portal.  As well, the newer ecobee3 model has remote sensors that can average "comfort" within a zone.